# How to get a date text field autofill

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a date text field to come auto fill.

Suppose I have a date, e.g. 4 January 2013, and I have a text field named "date". What I want is that this text field should come auto fill as 2013-1-4. How do I do this?

Comment: I don't want the current date like this..i want date in this format when i use any random date.

Comment: Do you have the date? Is someone supplying the date? Is it a string? Do we have to guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Current date:**

```
date = new Date().toISOString().match(/(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2})/);
$('input[name=date]').val(date[1]);
```

[current date demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fSP43/1/)

**Predefined date:**

```
var date = new Date("4 January 2013");
date = new Date(date.getTime()-date.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000)
       .toJSON()
       .match(/(\d{4})\-[0]?(\d{1,2})\-[0]?(\d{1,2})T/);
$('input[name=date]').val(date[1]+'-'+date[2]+'-'+date[3]);
```

[predefined date demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fSP43/4/)

Comment: Edited my answer, check it now

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date();

var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var day = d.getDate();

var output = d.getFullYear() + '/' +
 (month<10 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' +
 (day<10 ? '0' : '') + day;`
```

onload pls put this function in your page just need to do some programming stuff you will be done .

Comment: this will take the current date..i don't want the current date. i want any random dates.